# What is the best tool for network packet analyzing?

Tags: security

I want to perform penetration testing and assess the network traffic using a packet analyzer. Which tool is used by most people? How does it compare to other Applications, what is the state-of-the-art?

Is **Wireshark** the right choice as a network packet analyzer? How does it differ from an penetration-testing framework like e.g. *metasploit*?

What other applications are there?

Comment: Try wireshark, it is one of the best if not the best. 
Charles will work as well.

Comment: voting for Wireshark!!
Please see the below discussion,
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263116/wireshark-vs-firebug-vs-fiddler-pros-and-cons)

Comment: I would definitely say it is **Wireshark**. While there are other tools around, Wireshark offers a sophisticated GUI and virtually anything you need for analyzing network traffic.

If you are looking, on the other side, for sophisticated packet-forgeing software, **scappy** could be usefull to you, as it allows to arbitrarly forge any packets imagineable. It requires some practice, though. 

If you want to penetration-test your application, there is no distinct tool for this. 

Was just writing my answer when this was put [on hold], for whatever reason...